# SQl Query selecting 1 set of data over another

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope there's  enough information below for you to assist

TABA

ComapanyID TrimFields

1111   |    3

2222   |   1

3333   |   2

4444   |   4

5555   |    2

6666   |    3

TABB

SampleID | TestID | Microcomments  |ProductID  |ComapanyID

111101  |  Test1  |Satisfactory    |ABC123     | 1111

111101  | Test2   |No Test         |ABC123     | 1111

111101  | Test3   |Unsatisfactory  |ABC123     | 1111

222202  | Test2   |Satisfactory    |A21        | 2222

222202  | Test3   |Unsatisfactory  |A21        | 2222

333301  | Test1   |Satisfactory    |AB11       | 3333

333301  | Test3   |No Test         |AB11       | 3333

444403  | Test2   |Unsatisfactory  |ABCD123    | 4444

444403  | Test3   |No Test         |ABCD123    | 4444

555504  | Test1   |Unsatisfactory  |BA123      | 5555

555504  | Test2   |Unsatisfactory  |BA123      | 5555

666601  | Test3   |Satisfactory    |BBB21      | 6666

666601  | Test2   |Satisfactory    |BBB21      | 6666

---

At the moment my query is:
declare @num int

Set @companyID = @CompanyID

select  @num = isnull(trimfields,0)
from TABA where companyid = @companyID

select distinct TABB.SampleID, TABB.MicroComments,
        LTRIM(RIGHT(TABB.ProductID, len(rtrim(TABB.productID)) - @num)) as ProductID,

where TABB.CompanyID = @CompanyID

---

So when I run this Query for each CompanyID (WHERE CLAUSE) I get the following results

SampleID  Microcomments   ProductID

111101    Satisfactory    123

111101    NoTest          123

111101    Unsatisfactory  123

222202    Satisfactory    21
222202    Unsatisfactory  21

333301    Satisfactory    11
333301    NoTest          11

444403    Unsatisfactory  123
444403    NoTest          123

555504    Unsatisfactory  123
555504    Unsatisfactory  123

666601    Satisfactory    21
666601    Satisfactory    21

---

I need it to output  to be summarised with the folowing logic;

Logic 1- if the the sample id is the same but the Microcomment has Satis & Unsat & NoTest (EG. CompanyID 1111) 
then only show 'Unsatifactory'

Logic 2- if the the sample id is the same but the Microcomment has Satis & Unsati (EG. CompanyID 2222) 
then only show 'Unsatifactory'

Logic 3-  the the sample id is the same but the Microcomment has Satis & NoTest (EG.CompanyID 3333)
Then only Show 'Satisfactory'

Logic 4-  the the sample id is the same but the Microcomment has Unsat & NoTest (EG.CompanyID 4444)
Then only Show 'Unsatisfactory'

Logic 5-  the the sample id is the same but the Microcomment is only Unsat (EG.CompanyID 5555)
Then only Show 'Unsatisfactory'

Logic 5-  the the sample id is the same but the Microcomment is only Satis (EG.CompanyID 6666)
Then only Show 'Unsatisfactory'Then only Show 'Satisfactory'

---

So that the output would then be;

SampleID  Microcomments   ProductID
111101    Unsatisfactory  123

222202    Unsatisfactory  21

333301    Satisfactory    11

444403    Unsatisfactory  123

555504    Unsatisfactory  123

666601    Satisfactory    21

I’ve tried case statement, group by, Joins, MIN/MAX...just having no luck

Comment: Put your table structure and your current query attempt in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with the additional infos that you added to your question I gave it another try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TA1.ID, TA1.Name, TA1.Location, TB1.ID, TB1.Results
FROM TableA TA1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB TB1
    ON TB1.ID = TA1.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM TableB TB2
    WHERE TB2.ID = TA1.ID
      AND TB2.Results = 'UNSATISFACTORY')
      OR TB1.Results = 'UNSATISFACTORY';
```

This should match your requirements stated in the question. It selects the joined information from `TableA` and `TableB`, removes double items with the `DISTINCT` so that multiple satisfactory or NOT TESTED items get only one result record, and filters out other items in case there is an UNSATISFACTORY record in the `TableB` for a specific Id.

You can also have a look here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b202/6

**Original Answer**

I try to answer your question based on a few assumptions. One is that your table structure is the same as your query output. Another one is the table and column names.

You could try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, location, yesorno
FROM TestTable T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable T2 
    WHERE T2.name = T1.name 
      AND T2.location = T1.location
      AND T2.yesorno = 'No')
      OR T1.yesorno = 'No';
```

The `DISTINCT` is only needed if it's possible in your data to have more than one record for the same `name`, `location` and `yesorno`.

See:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/546354/7

Comment: Every time i add the 'WHERE NOT EXISTS' Clause I'm getting the following error message 'Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function'----Thank you for your help

Comment: There is no RIGHT function used in the sample. It would help a lot if you would add more information to your question. The query you are using, the tables used and their columns including their datatypes. I don't have enough information to help you further right now.

Comment: Hi ive uploaded a more detailed explanation of the setup without using original table and column names.

Comment: @KunalVaja I updated my answer according to your edit.

Comment: @PhilipGrathwohl apologies for not uploading the correct info, i've updated it once again and created the table on SQLfiddle (Very Useful) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b76c8c/4/0

Comment: @PhilipGrathwohl is there a way to write a query with the updated example. many thanks for your input

Comment: Sorry I wouldn't know how to achieve your requirements in one query. Maybe you should use multiple steps to gather your data. E.g. first query all unsatisfactory results to a temp-table as they overrule the other ones. Then select all satisfactory ones that do not match the company ids of the previously selected ones. And last select the no test ones that do not match the previous two result ids. I'm afraid Sqlfiddle does not allow temp tables, so it's not possible to test this online ...